Text different from details of an event
In Bereshit (Genesis) - Chapter 18, pasuk 13 says, 'And the Lord said to Abraham, "Why did Sarah laugh, saying, 'Is it really true that I will give birth, although I am old?''
Rashi on this pasuk says:
וַֽאֲנִי זָקַֽנְתִּי: שִׁנָּה הַכָּתוּב מִפְּנֵי הַשָּׁלוֹם, שֶׁהֲרֵי הִיא אָמְרָה וַאדֹנִי זָקֵן:
although I am old: Scripture altered [her statement] for the sake of peace, for she had said, “and my master is old.” - [from B.M. 87a]
I heard of spelling a word a certain way but pronouncing it another; but it seems this is the only place where one thing happened but something else was written down.
Can anyone share other pasukim, or incidents where one thing transpired but some thing else was written down?
Disclaimer: As the Alter Rebbe says, the Universe belongs to the Great one above, and he can obviously do, say, and ofcourse write what he wants.

Even this case doesn't seem to meet your criteria because the Torah does record what actually happened, and what you are bringing is Hashem's statement about it to Avraham. I.e. the event is recorded, and exactly as it happened.

@RabbiKaii What do you mean? Sarah Immeinu said, 'My master is Old', but what was written down was ' Although I am old'. That is a clear cut case of one thing happening but something else was written down.

Interesting. שנה הכתוב sounds like it was changed in the Torah's retelling, but מפני השלום implies Hashem told it differently to Avraham.

There are famously 18 תיקוני סופרים where the text is "changed" to something else

@MarsSojourner how do you know she actually said "My master is old"? Because the Torah records it.

@RabbiKaii Rashi says that she said, ' Scripture altered [her statement] for the sake of peace, for she had said, “and my master is old.” - [from B.M. 87a]'.

@MarsSojourner 18:12: ותצחק שרה בקרבה לאמר אחרי בלתי היתה־לי עדנה ואדני זקן "And Sarah laughed to herself, saying, “Now that I’ve lost the ability, am I to have enjoyment—with my husband so old?”"

Given the context, it seems to me that הַכָּתוּב must be used here as a nickname for God. See also the Midrash that this statement of Rashi is based on. The peace being established here is between Avraham Avinu and Sara Imeinu, so it's within the context of the story, so the mechanism for establishing peace is God's choice of words in speaking to Avraham, not just His choice of words when recording the conversation in the Torah.

Maybe it can be read as "the change in the verse is because [Hashem reported it differently to Avraham] for the sake of harmony"

When Avraham's employee (who we'll assume is Eliezer) recounts his story for Rivkah's family, there are some minor differences. As there are between how Moshe retells certain events in Parshas Devarim and how they were listed earlier.

Moshe's recollection of 10 commandments in Devarim is different from the original version. The dream of Pharaoh is different from how he presented it to Yosef.

In parshas Ki Sisa (Shemos 32:22) Aharon’s account of the eigel is markedly different than the Torah’s. This too seems to be מפני השלום.

Bereshit 12:18:

ויקרא פרעה לאברם ויאמר מה־זאת עשית לי למה לא־הגדת לי כי אשתך הוא
And Par῾o called Avram, and said, What is this that thou hast done to
me? why didst thou not tell me that she was thy wife?

It is highly unlikely Pharaoh spoke Lashon Hakodesh. Especially when speaking to fellow Egyptians in 41:9 onwards.
