What does Bereshit Rabbah mean when it says the Scriptures spoke untruths?
As far as I can tell Bereshit Rabbah 48:18 says that G-d actually repeated everything Sarah said to Abraham including that he was old, but the Torah falsely says that G-d only told Abraham that Sarah said that she was old in order to avoid strife between Abraham and Sarah.  How does this fit with the belief that the scriptures are inerrant, especially since this passage seems to make perfect sense with its plain meaning?

I am confused. Hashem said "I am old" and scripture says He said "I am old", so it is inerrant

Very related (based on the same misunderstanding) https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/143620/text-different-from-details-of-an-event

Is ketuvim a euphemism for G-d in this case?

There are many cases in the Torah where untruths are spoken for the sake of a good cause, and God clearly approves.

@MauriceMizrahi Yes, but can the Torah itself say things that aren't true? It seems that Rashi believed that ketuvim was a euphemism for G-d which makes sense because the Torah records her "insulting" Abraham in v12 anyway.  In any case, G-d didn't say anything that wasn't true; it was more of a paraphrasal.

In Exodus, God says “borrow” when He obviously means “take”:
Every woman shall borrow from her neighbor and from her who sojourns in her house: Jewels of silver, and jewels of gold, and garments.  And you shall put them upon your sons, and upon your daughters; and you shall plunder the Egyptians. [Ex. 3:22]

God also instructs Moses to lie to Pharaoh:
-You shall go... to the king of Egypt, and you shall say to him, “The Lord God of the Hebrews has met with us; and now let us go, we beseech you, for a three-day journey in the wilderness, so that we may sacrifice to the Lord our God.” [Ex. 3:18]
God certainly had more than a three-day round trip in mind!

You misunderstand the text.  Let's take a look.

“The Lord said to Abraham: Why is it that Sarah laughed, saying: Shall
I indeed bear a child, and I have grown old?” (Genesis 18:13).  “The
Lord said to Abraham: Why is it that Sarah laughed, saying: [Shall I
indeed bear a child, and I have grown old?]” – bar Kappara said: Peace
[between spouses] is a great thing, as even Scripture spoke untruths
in order to establish peace between Abraham and Sarah. “Sarah laughed
to herself, saying: After my languishing, shall I have youth, and my
husband is old?” But He did not say this to Abraham, but rather, “Why
is it that Sarah laughed, saying: Shall I indeed bear a child, and I
have grown old?” The verse does not say as Sarah said: “My husband is
old,” but rather, “I have grown old.”

The Medrash notes that Hashem deliberately misreported Sarah's comments to Avraham.  Whereas she had commented that her husband, Avraham, was old, Hashem told Avraham that she had said that she herself was old.  This was not an error on His part, nor an error on the part of the Torah as to what He said.  He said this, and He said it intentionally.  The purpose was to uphold marital peace between Avraham and Sarah, as Avraham might feel offended if he heard that his wife regarded him as elderly.
Again, when Sarah heard that she would yet have a child, she said "How can this be?  My husband is too old."
When Hashem discussed this with Avraham, He said that Sarah had said "How can this be?  I am too old."
Chazal note the discrepancy, and explain that Hashem is here teaching us that it is correct behavior to tell "white lies" in order to maintain peace between people, particularly between married couples.

Might be worth flagging and explaining the cause of the misunderstanding - the midrash (in this translation) referring to Hashem as "Scripture"

According to YLT Sarah said "I have waxed old," so G-d didn't say something false He just didn't tell Abraham everything she said.  I just don't understand why they would conclude that G-d spoke falsely if it's not even necessary to make sense of the passage.

Who is YLT?  Hashem saw fit to misreport Sarah's words, leaving out the part about "my husband is old."  Like everything in Scripture, this is meant to be a lesson for us.
